# StringTokenizer method equivalence

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

Why do `hasMoreElements` and `hasMoreTokens` return the same value?

Comment: Looks like this is one of your first questions. Here's a tip, on Stack Overflow we ask questions and others answer them with the hope that someone else may be able to use your question to find the same answer to the issue that they may be having. If you are going to post a question, please provide some code that shows what you are asking.

Comment: Looking at the answer this seems to be a valid question.

Answer (score 7):

From the javadoc of hasMoreElements()

```
/** 
* Returns the same value as the hasMoreTokens
* method. It exists so that this class can implement the
* Enumeration interface.
*/
```

[Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#hasMoreElements%28%29)

Comment: Pick one, since both do the same work, but I would pick `hasMoreTokens` since that method name explains better what it does.

Comment: You should in that case indicate mark an answer as correct (I think, I have never posted any questions here)

Answer (score 0):

since this is a legacy class which implements Enumeration it also uses the method hasMoreTokens for simplicity method naming.

In simple case which uses just the StringTokenizer you can use the hasMoreTokens method. In polymorphic case which you created or already has more implementation of the Enumeraion interface you will use the hasMoreElements which is part of the Enumeraion interface.

Comment: In simple case which uses just the StringTokenizer you can use the hasMoreTokens method. In polymorphic case which you created or already has more implementation of the Enumeraion interface you will use the hasMoreElements which is part of the Enumeraion interface (updated my answer)